# Thunderbird calendar is only showing a plain one month calendar page. I can't get it to go to the page that shows schedules

Tags: thunderbird, calendar

I'm running Windows 11 Pro, 23H2 and am using Thunderbird for  email and calendars. I can sync with Google Calendar OK since the add-in is installed, but the only panel I can get it to show is a single calendar page for the currrent month but all it shows is a small dot under days that have something scheduled (plus tasks that I don't care about) but not the one with my choice of Days, Months, etc. and the schedules for each day. I've shown an example of the page I'm looking for on Thurderbird. It's from Google Calendar online.
I would show you screen shots but I don't know how to do that here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally found the secret! I went through the action bar (sorry if that's not the right term) item by item until I found  View > Calendar > Calendar Pane > turned off View Calendar Pane. I had not intentionally turned it on but had slid a couple of things sideways to see what they were and I couldn't get back to the Calendar page. Thanks.